# What is the correct terminology for "->", ie $class->method()

Tags: terminology

```
$class->method()
      ^
      |
```

What's the correct terminology for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always called the symbol an "arrow".

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the language:

-PHP, I believe its just used to access a class members

-C or C++ on the other hand, it is used to derefernce a pointer and access a member. It's pretty much just syntactic sugar.

```
pointer->member
```

is equivalent to

```
(*pointer).member
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's called the "arrow notation", assuming of course you are talking about PHP. Thats what most publications, articles and the PHP website call it, so that's what my brain says on sight.

Answer (score 1):

Member access operator.

Comment: This one sounds most 'correct' to me if, as it looks like, we're talking PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think C++ calls it “pointer member access operator.“

Answer (score 0):

i would say: dereference operator

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

after some discussions with good commenters, the final terminology could be:

dereference and field access operator
that could be shorten into:
- field access operator

Comment: dereference is different, it provides the address that the pointer points to, not access to the underlying object

Comment: see the java example where . is the derefence operator

Comment: Not really. If anything it would be the "access member operator" as in t's usually used as syntactic sugar to access members of a pointer, as in C/C++(That is it's a dereference operator + a field access operator) or is simply the default way to access a field, as in perl.

Comment: agree, the php -> is a dereference+field access operator !

Answer (score 0):

It's the "member selection" operator or "member by pointer" operator.

[MSDN Library: C++ operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x04xhy0h%28VS.80%29.aspx)
[Wikipedia: C++ opreators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it is called the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`. See the [List of Parser Tokens in the PHP Manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)